# Angular 2 select with (change) event, not updating value in dropdown

Tags: angular, select, dropdown

When the select dropdown changes, I call a method with the `(change)` directive to check if the value selected is allowed, if the selected value is not allowed, I select the previous value again (revert the change on the dropdown), but the selected value in die dropdown still shows the new selected value, but the `ngModel` variable is the previous value e.g. :

I change the select from A to B.

**HTML:**

```html
<select (change)="doCheck()" [(ngModel)]="test">
    <option [ngValue]="1">A</option>
    <option [ngValue]="2">B</option>
</select>
```

**Component:**

```js
test: number = 1;

doCheck(){  
     //Not allowed to change to B, so change back to A
     this.test = 1;
}
```

The `test` variable value is 1, but B is still selected in the dropdown.

However when I add a `setTimeout` on `this.test = 1` then the value change back to A, but I don't want to add `setTimeout` everywhere in my code.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Use `ngModelChange` instead

```
<select (ngModelChange)="doCheck()" [(ngModel)]="test">
```

to ensure `doCheck()` is called after `ngModel` updated `test`

Angular doesn't guarantee event bindings to be processed in any specific order. But `ngModelChange` is emitted by `NgModel` after it updated the model.

If you modify the value back that `ngModel` did update you probably need

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

doCheck(){  
     //Not allowed to change to B, so change back to A
     this.test = 1;
     this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

otherwise `ngModel` might keep the old value.

Comment: I already tried that, but still not updating the select value in the HTML and with `(ngModelChange)` I won't know what the new selected value is

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "I won't know what the new selected value is". The new selected value is already assigned to `this.test` when `ngModelChange()` was called. You can also explicitly pass it like `(ngModelChange)="doCheck($event)"`

Comment: When `(ngModelChange)` is in front of `[(ngModel)]` then `[(ngModel)]` is only assigned after `(ngModelChange)` is called. So I moved `[(ngModel)]` in front of `(ngModelChange)`, then `[(ngModel)]` is assigned before `(ngModelChange)` is called, but still the select dropdown showing **B** and not **A**, although `this.test` is 1

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not true "When (ngModelChange) is in front of [(ngModel)] then [(ngModel)] is only updated after (ngModelChange) function.". As mentioned in my answer, the order of events on an element is irrelevant and has no influence in what order the event handlers are called. Your code should not depend on the events called in any specific order. `ngModelChange` works because it is emitted by the `NgModel` directive after it updated the model.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Obaid. This is because you have `(ngModelChange)` twice. Change `[(ngModel)]="test"` to `[ngModel]="test"` and update `this.test` yourself from `doCheck()`.